# Performing actions / working with gestures via Live Preview (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, action, gesture, preview

I have `CustomToggle` and I want to test it via `Live Preview`. The problem is that tapping on toggle via `Live Preview` does nothing, but works well when running `Simulator`.

```
struct CustomToggle: View {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool

    // ... displaying CustomToggle view
    // ... and toggling isON onTapGesture

}
```

```
struct CustomToggle_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var isOn = true
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomToggle(isOn: $isOn)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a struct for this purpose:

```swift
struct StatefulPreviewWrapper<Value, Content: View>: View {
    @State var value: Value
    var content: (Binding<Value>) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        content($value)
    }

    init(_ value: Value, content: @escaping (Binding<Value>) -> Content) {
        self._value = State(wrappedValue: value)
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

Then use it in your preview like this:

```swift
struct CustomToggle_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StatefulPreviewWrapper(false) { CustomToggle(isOn: $0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but is it only one way? In this case, I will have to declare struct for every count of arguments used in `View` which I want to preview.